# AWS ScheduleExpression is not valid

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, cron, aws-cloudformation

I want my schedule to run every night at 00:00.

So in cloud formation I have set:

ScheduleExpression: "cron(0 0 * * * *)"

But it fails the deployment saying that ScheduleExpression is not correct. Any hints?

Comment: Looks fine, are you setting that expression statically or in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS cron works a bit different. For your case try cron(0 0 * * ? *). You can read more here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html